# R: Remove substring within string

Tags: r, substring, substitution

Is there an elegant way to remove a sub-string within a string based on the index of the characters?

Here is how I do it now:

```
# My data
mystring <- "Hello, how are {you} doing?"
index_of_substring <- c(16,20)

# Pasting two substrings
mystring_no_substring <- paste0(substr(mystring, 1, index_of_substring[1]-1), substr(mystring, index_of_substring[2]+1, nchar(mystring)))

# Cleaning extra spaces
mystring_no_substring <- gsub("  ", " ", mystring_no_substring)
```

I could of course write this up to a general function, but I was just wondering if there was an elegant solution out there, e.g. to substitute an index in a string with nothing or another word.

Note: This is not a regex question.

Comment: `stringi::stri_sub(mystring, 16, 20) <- ""` for example?

Comment: Yeah, that is already much more elegant! Thanks.

Comment: Another Option is: `stringr::str_sub(mystring, 16, 20) <- ""`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1) strsplit/paste** Break up the input into characters, omit the ones between 16 and 20 inclusive,  collapse it back together and replace runs of spaces with single spaces.  Uses base functions only.

```
gsub(" +", " ", paste(strsplit(s, "")[[1]][-seq(ix[1], ix[2])], collapse = ""))
## [1] "Hello, how are doing?"
```

**2) substr<-** Replace the indicated characters with spaces and then reduce runs of spaces to a single space.  Only base functions are used.

```
gsub(" +", " ", "substr<-"(s, ix[1],  ix[2], gsub(".", " ", s)))
## [1] "Hello, how are doing?"
```

Note that this is non-destructive, i.e. it outputs the result without modifying the input.

**Note:** We used test input:

```
s <- "Hello, how are {you} doing?"
ix <- c(16, 20)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `paste0` and `substr` like this too:-

```
paste0(substr(mystring, 1, 14), substr(mystring, 21, 27))
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe my solution is pretty much what you'd get if coded your method as a general function but here you go. I first use a custom function called "strpos_fixed" to index the substring I'd like to remove. I not quite as comfotable as I'd like to be with regex so I restrict this function to fixed matching for simplicity sake.

```
strpos_fixed=function(x,y){
  a<-regexpr(y, x,fixed=T)
  b<-a[1]
  return(b)
}


rm_substr<-function(string,rm_start,rm_end){

  sub1<-substr(string,1,strpos_fixed(string, rm_start)-1)

  sub2<-substr(string, strpos_fixed(string,rm_end)+nchar(rm_end), 
               nchar(string))

  new <- gsub("\\s{2,}"," ",paste(sub1, sub2))

  return(new)
}

mystring <- "Hello, how are {you} doing?"
rm_substr(mystring, "{", "}")
```